# Python grabbing an <a> value from a table is not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this html

```
<tr class="BgWhite">
  <td headers="th0" valign="top">
    3
  </td>
  <td headers="th1" style="width: 125px;" valign="top">
    <a href="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/RFQ/RFQNsn.aspx?value=8340015511310&amp;category=issue&amp;Scope=" title="go to NSN view">8340-01-551-1310</a>
  </td>
```

I want to find this number id "8340-01-551-1310" so I used this code

```
 test = container1.find_all("td", {"headers": "th1"})
 test1 = test.find_all("a", {"title":"go to NSN view"})
```

but it displays this message

```
"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a  list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

what am I doing wrongly and how do I fix this?

Comment: it's telling you that `test` is a `ResultSet` which has more than one item. did you print `test` and take a look at it?

Comment: Your first call to find_all returns a list. If you iterate that list, you can search the members of this list, but you can't ask a list to "find_all" since that isn't a method of a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<tr class="BgWhite">
  <td headers="th0" valign="top">
    3
  </td>
  <td headers="th1" style="width: 125px;" valign="top">
    <a href="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/RFQ/RFQNsn.aspx?value=8340015511310&amp;category=issue&amp;Scope=" title="go to NSN view">8340-01-551-1310</a>
  </td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

for td in soup.find_all('td', {"headers": "th1"}):
    for a in td.find_all('a'):
        print(a.text)
```

Output:

```
8340-01-551-1310
```

However, if you are sure you will have only one "th1" or just want the first one. And if you are sure that will have only one "a" or you just want the first one. You could try:

```
print(soup.find('td', {"headers": "th1"}).find('a').text)
```

Which returns the same output.

EDIT:
Just noticed it could be simplified to:

```
print(soup.find('td', {"headers": "th1"}).a.text)
```